# Global Raster over GPS Data

Tags: java, gps, geocoding, geospatial, raster

i want to build a global raster over all GPS coordinates.
The cells should be like 20x20 metres...
I want to write an java application and 'work with'/adjust that raster later on.
For example to get the cell for a single gps coordinate or maybe even combine two cells to a bigger one (not necessary).

Can anyone give me an advice for an API or something else that could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already answered to a similar question, you cannot create a raster expressed in meters, without prior transforming all coordinates to a meter based x,y (= cartesian) coordinate system.
The GPS coordinates are spherical ones, the cell sizes (especially the y or latitudinal span) would vary from cell to cell, when going North or South.

So either express your raster size in decimal degrees (use an equivalent of your desired with (20m) expressed in meters at center of your area of interest).
Note: The Earth circumfence = 40.000 km, so 40.000 / 360 degrees give 111.111 km as length related to 1 degrees; use this factor to calculate the number of degrees related to 20m.

Or you transform all coordinates to UTM.
Having them in UTM you can then implement a raster expressed in meters.
Difficuties for UTM apporach: This projection is only valid at a longitudinal span of 3 degrees, you will get major problems when the location have to croiss this 3 degree limit.

There is no API for that, that I know, but you can implement that using a 2 dimensional array. (There are APIs for transfroming a lat/lon coordinate to UTM)

If the area of interest is larger then one country this approach may not work (well). The array could be to big.

In that case this task gets more complex, you would need a spatial index, like a quadtree, to limit the number of raster elements, by having an adaptive behaviour for dense locations.